# Dock window in win32 c++

Tags: c++, winapi

Can you dock a child window control in C++ win32 API (like are there WS_* styles or something), or do you always have to listen for the WM_SIZE message on the parent window and manually re-layout/fill all the children?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing directly available in the WinAPI that will automate this, it's generally implemented by framework wrappers (like MFC...). However, there are a few libraries (such as [this](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=9416&lngWId=3) one) that you could use as an alternative to implementing it from scratch.