# Parent child window issue in VC++ non mfc

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

The below code works fine but when I place mouse on the parent window and drag it,  the child and parent window gets separted. But I want that child and parent window moves together and not get separated, when I place mouse and move it. I tried some stuffs like WS_DISABLED for child window but it did not worked. please let me know what modification needs to be done. My application is non MFC.Below is my code:

```
void displayProgressBar()
{
HINSTANCE g_hinst;
if( (g_hinst = GetModuleHandle( L"LoadFunc.dll" )) == NULL )
{
    g_hinst = GetModuleHandle( 0 );
}
RECT screenSize;

InitCommonControls();
BOOL rc = SystemParametersInfo( SPI_GETWORKAREA, 0, &screenSize, 0 );
int height = screenSize.bottom / 15;
int width = screenSize.right / 3;
int x = (screenSize.bottom / 2) - (height / 2);
int y = (screenSize.right / 2) - (width / 2);

//  create a static window, display a graphic and attach a progress bar to it.
wchar_t currentDir[MAX_PATH];
_wgetcwd( currentDir, _MAX_PATH );
HANDLE img = LoadImage(g_hinst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0,  LR_DEFAULTCOLOR );
//MessageBox(0,L"in",L"out",MB_OK);
hwndParent = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME | WS_EX_STATICEDGE,
                          WC_STATIC,
                          L"install in progress",
                          WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | SS_BITMAP,
                          x,
                          y,
                          CW_USEDEFAULT,
                          CW_USEDEFAULT,
                          hwndParent,
                          NULL,
                          g_hinst,
                          NULL) ;
                          EnableWindow(hwndPB,FALSE);
SendMessage(hwndParent, STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)img);
RECT RectControl;
::GetWindowRect( hwndParent, &RectControl );

//MessageBox(0,L"1",L"1",MB_OK);
hwndPB = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME | WS_EX_STATICEDGE,
    PROGRESS_CLASS,
    NULL,
    WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE,
    x + 10, // x
    RectControl.bottom - 25, // y
    RectControl.right - RectControl.left - 20, // width
    20, // height
    hwndParent,
    (HMENU) 0,
    g_hinst,
    NULL);
    EnableWindow(hwndPB,FALSE);

SendMessage(hwndPB, PBM_SETRANGE, 0,
            MAKELPARAM(0, 25));
SendMessage(hwndPB, PBM_SETSTEP, (WPARAM) 2, 0);
}
```

Thanks in advance for providing help.

Comment: Consider renaming your question: "How to lock the relative position of child window to its parent?"

Comment: And if that last question is what you are asking, then the answer can be found here: [How to bind child windows to parent window in relative positions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302225/how-to-bind-child-windows-to-parent-window-in-relative-positions)

Comment: @HuguesFontenelle Thank you for response. can we do any modification in the code I posted to work as per my requirement.

Comment: `if( (g_hinst = GetModuleHandle( L"LoadFunc.dll" )) == NULL )` - why did you opt to not handle errors? If a required module isn't loaded, terminate the application. Don't fear throwing an uncaught exception - it tremendously helps finding errors early, instead of masking them. @Hugues: This questions is about the Windows API. Claiming that *"Parents get moved independently from children"* is wrong in the context of the question domain. Either provide facts (documentation) or remove the comments (the latter is highly recommended).

Comment: @IInspectable My take is that this is a default in most gui, but I'm not well versed in the windows API, so I removed the comment.

Comment: @Hugues: Your (now) first comment is also meaningless. The relative **position** of child windows inside their respective parent window is fixed already. The link in your second comment solves a different issue altogether: **Resizing** and **Repositioning** child windows when the parent window changes in **size**.

Answer (score 1):

The `hMenu` parameter for [CreateWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680.aspx) is overloaded, and has two distinct meanings depending on the `dwStyle` parameter. Here are the important pieces of information from the documentation:

> For an overlapped or pop-up window, *hMenu* identifies the menu to be used with the window.
>
> For a child window, *hMenu* specifies the child-window identifier.

Passing `NULL` is allowed for an overlapped or pop-up window, if the class menu is to be used. On the other hand, passing `0` for a child window is not allowed: 0 is not a valid control identifier. (This isn't spelled out explicitly, but can be easily deduced from the fact that [GetDlgCtrlID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645478.aspx) and [GetWindowLongPtr [GWLP_ID]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633585.aspx) return 0 to indicate an error.)

To fix your issue you have to apply two changes: Specify the `WS_CHILD` window style, and assign a valid child-window ID:

```
hwndPB = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_STATICEDGE,
    PROGRESS_CLASS,
    NULL,
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
    x + 10, // x
    RectControl.bottom - 25, // y
    RectControl.right - RectControl.left - 20, // width
    20, // height
    hwndParent,
    (HMENU) 1,    // child-window identifier; this is usually defined as a named
                  // constant in Resource.h
    g_hinst,
    NULL);
```

Comment: Thank you for response I tried the approach shared by you. But on using WS_CHILD progress bar is not displayed.

Comment: @helper: Remove the `WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME` [Extended Window Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543.aspx), and add the `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` [Window Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600.aspx) to the control **parent**. Adding error handling doesn't hurt either. Consult the respective API documentation to learn how errors are reported.

Comment: I tried the changes advised but still the progress bar is not visible.

Comment: @helper: Make sure to use *Client coordinates* when creating a child window (see [Window Coordinate Systems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145205.aspx) for details). As suggested earlier, do check for errors, as outlined in the API [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need WS_CHILD style for hwndPB... WS_POPUP means that "child" window is simply disabling the parent, and they are not moved together.

BTW, "non MFC" is also known as Win32 app.

Comment: I tried WS_CHILD style for hwndPB and WS_DISABLED. But when I do this progress bar is not visible. It is only visible when I use WS_POPUP.

Comment: WS_DISABLED is not necessary. Only WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE (without WS_POPUP). If the window is not shown, try with ShowWindow if hwndPB is not null. Your WS_EX_ flags are not compatible with WS_CHILD window - you may use classic CreateWindow() API. If return value is NULL, use GetLastError() get more information about the error. Also, put value <>0 for HMENU parameter (it is the ID of child window). Note that coordinates of child windows are relative to its parent, e.g. 0,0 is the upper left corner no matter of the position of parent.

Comment: I have already tried with WS_CHILD the progress bar is not visible in that case. I will try with classic CraeteWindow().

Comment: Use GetClientRect() instead of GetWindowRect() and then for X, Y, CX, CY - use 0, 0, RectControl.right, RectControl.bottom. In addition you have to resize the child control on each WM_SIZE message for parent window (if parent is sizeable).

Comment: Yes this helped. Thank you. But my window is not having any button or close,minimize or maximize option. Now i need to close this window after specific time out forcibly and free all the handles. I am not able to achieve this. As a result window is displayed continuously.

Comment: Use DestroyWindow( hwndPB )